# How do I swap elements in an ArrayList with respect to another ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, swap, knapsack-problem

Okay, so I'm trying to solve the Knapsack problem. What I've done so far is this:

1) Created three ArrayLists- Weight, Profit & Score (Profit/Weight)
2) Created a duplicate of Score
3) Sorted the Scores in descending order

As you can see, the next step has to be to change the positions of elements in the Weight and Profit ArrayList according to the descending order of Score

I'm having a bit of a problem doing this.
Initially, I thought the following would do the trick:

(P - profit ArrayList, W - weight ArrayList, S - Descending score ArrayList, D - Original Score ArrayList)

```
public void UpdateWandP(ArrayList <Double> P, ArrayList <Double> W, ArrayList <Double> S, ArrayList <Double> D){
    for(int i=0;i<P.size();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<P.size();j++){
            if(D.get(i) == S.get(j)){
                Swap(i,j,W);
                Swap(i,j,P);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void Swap(int i, int j, ArrayList <Double> A){
    Collections.swap(A,i,j);
}
```

However, I can't seem to get the correct ordering.

For e.g., If I were to add the following in my code:

```
P = {9,7,12,6,5}
W = {13,9,18,8,7}
```

I would get a Score ArrayList like:

```
S = {0.69,0.77,0.66,0.75,0.71}
```

I would duplicate this Score ArrayList

Now, I arrange S in descending order

```
S = {0.77,0.75,0.71,0.67,0.66}
```

The output I'm getting is this:

```
Profits: [9.0, 7.0, 12.0, 6.0, 5.0]
Weights: [13.0, 9.0, 18.0, 8.0, 7.0]
Scores: [0.6923076923076923, 0.7777777777777778, 0.6666666666666666, 0.75, 0.7142857142857143]
New Score: [0.7777777777777778, 0.75, 0.7142857142857143, 0.6923076923076923, 0.6666666666666666]
Updated P: [6.0, 7.0, 12.0, 9.0, 5.0]
Updated W: [8.0, 9.0, 18.0, 13.0, 7.0]
```

Relative to the new Score ArrayList, how can I make changes in the Profit and Weight ArrayLists as well?

Answer (score 2):

Consider instead of three lists, having a single list of a custom `Item` class (`List<Item>`).

The class `Item` will have a `weight` and `profit` member variables and the class will implement `Comparable`. You can then define the `compareTo()` method to order on `score = profit / weight` and then you can sort the list with `Collections.sort()`. This makes sure all weights / profits / scores are consistent and you only have to work with a single list.

The class `Item` would look something like this . . .

```
public class Item implements Comparable {
    double weight;
    double profit;

    // Constructor, Getters, and Setters

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item other) {
       // sort descending on score
    }

    // optional getter method for score (don't necessarily need to store the score in member variable)
    public double getScore() {
       return this.profit / this.weight;
    }

}
```

and you can sort your list like this . . .

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
     List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
     // add items
     Collections.sort(items);
     // list is now sorted on score
}
```

If you want to sort the list in multiple ways, you can define `Comparator` classes to sort on different / multiple fields. Then you can use `Collections.sort(List<Item>,Comparator<Item>)` for sorting.